# Convert your Stack Exchange Posts to your own Website

Tags: app, discussion, posts, data-explorer

Using the tools in this [website](https://pippim.github.io) you can take all your Stack Exchange Posts in SE Markdown Format and convert them to GitHub Pages Jekyll Kramdown format.

The website is targeted to high-rep Stack Exchange users who want to take all their SE Network posts and create their own website from them. The website created will have Tables of Contents and Section Navigation buttons on lengthy posts.

Simply copy (fork/clone) the entire website and change the name to your own. Then run a SEDE query every Monday morning to update the website content with your Stack Exchange Posts.

Converting SE Markdown to GitHub Pages Jekyll Kramkdown is not an easy task but the tools on the website make it as easy as running "refresh.sh" once a week.

Comment: Well, actually we would like to do the contrary: Convert our web site post sto StackExchange.. Any idea how we could do that ?

Comment: > If that is possible can you prove it with a webpage that is converted from a post from stackapps.com?

Comment: It will be beneficial for everyone if you used the [app template](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=app) for the announcement (or the script one depending on your preferences).

Comment: @Bossanova That is a great idea but sadly, I haven't thought of doing that.

Comment: @MorristheDon Sure. Click the link in the question, select "Answers" to list 1,123 converted Stack Exchange posts, pick the first converted GithHub Pages post. At the top of the GitHub Pages post is a link to see the original answer posted in Stack Exchange. If you prefer I could make an animated gif that shows this in action.

Comment: @OlegValter That is a great template. Thank you for the link and I'll work on getting a polished version published.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thumbsup - the benefit of Stack Apps is that we have what most other sites on the network do not (and as I am sure you know has been requested multiple times) - question templates

Comment: @MorristheDon I created a [video](https://pippim.github.io/stack.html) showing how to rebuild website (in under a minute) scanning 2800 SE posts and converting the better ones into 1123 GitHub Jekyll Posts. The video also shows how the SE post looks on SE and how it looks (much better) in GitHub Pages.

Comment: @OlegValter I completed the template and created a [new post](https://stackapps.com/questions/9329/convert-stack-exchange-posts-to-your-own-website). Thanks for the help.